# Spring boot not scanning sub-sub-packages of main package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have reason to believe Spring Boot is not scanning for, at a minimum, an entity class despite the entity being in a sub-sub-package of the main package. I had gotten it to work with an @ComponentScan annotation, at least somewhat. However, I noticed another component also was not running. I'm sure this something very simple because this is a very close copy from a different package.

Note: I tried adding @ComponentScan, @EntityScan,@EnableJpaRepositories. This had gotten rid of the original error, but it did not pick up @Service GenerateFileService (shown below), so I added the corresponding package to all of the annotations. I had thought @SpringBootApplication would automagically find all the relevant Spring beans provided all classes were under a sub-package of the Application, but this was not so.

The stack trace is:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-04-19 06:28:48 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'generateFileService' defined in file [C:\projects-new\cirrus-bluecost-ssc-file-generator\target\classes\com\mycomp\cloud\cost\ssc\file\generator\application\GenerateFileService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'costDataRepository' defined in com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostDataRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on BlueCostSSCFileGeneratorApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostData
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
        at com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.BlueCostSSCFileGeneratorApplication.main(BlueCostSSCFileGeneratorApplication.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'costDataRepository' defined in com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostDataRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on BlueCostSSCFileGeneratorApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostData
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostData
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:229)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:162)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:72)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:309)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
        ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Main application:

```
package com.mycompany.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator")
@ComponentScan({"com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model","com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application","com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.infrastructure.persistence","com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.infrastructure.persistence.file.system","com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.configuration"}) /* ,"com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostData" */
@EntityScan({"com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model","com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application","com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.infrastructure.persistence","com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.infrastructure.persistence.file.system","com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.configuration"}) /* ,"com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostData" */
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model","com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application","com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.infrastructure.persistence","com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.einfrastructure.persistence.file.system","com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.configuration"},
basePackageClasses = com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostDataRepository.class)
public class BlueCostSSCFileGeneratorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SpringApplication.run(BlueCostSSCFileGeneratorApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

GenerateFileService:

```
package com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application;

import java.util.List;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application.util.LogLayer;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application.util.LogType;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application.util.LogUtils;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.configuration.FileGeneratorProperties;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostData;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostDataRepository;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.SSCFileDescriptor;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.csv.CsvFileGenerator;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.ebcdic.EBCDICFileGenerator;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.infrastructure.persistence.file.system.FileWriter;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.infrastructure.port.email.EmailService;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.process.model.LastRunResult;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.process.model.RunResult;
import com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.process.model.RunResultService;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class GenerateFileService {

    @Autowired
    private final CostDataRepository costDataRepository;
    private FileWriter fileWriter;
    private final FileGeneratorProperties properties;
    private static final String CREATE_FILES = "CREATE_FILES";
    private Logger logger;
    private final ObjectFactory<SSCFileDescriptor> fileDescriptorFactory;
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private RunResultService runResultService;
    private EmailService emailService;

    public GenerateFileService(CostDataRepository costDataRepository, FileWriter fileWriter, FileGeneratorProperties properties,
                               ObjectFactory<SSCFileDescriptor> fileDescriptorFactory,
                               BeanFactory beanFactory, RunResultService runResultService,
                               EmailService emailService) {
        this.costDataRepository = costDataRepository;
        this.fileWriter = fileWriter;
        this.properties = properties;
        this.fileDescriptorFactory = fileDescriptorFactory;
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
        this.runResultService = runResultService;
        this.emailService = emailService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setLogger(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    @Transactional
    public FileGenerationResult createFiles() {
        /* Code omitted */
        return result;
    }


}
```

CostData Entity

```
package com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Entity
public class CostData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long costDataId;
    @Column(name = "COSTINGAMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal totalChargesAmount;


    public Long getCostDataId() {
        return costDataId;
    }


}
```

CostDataRepository.java

```
package com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface CostDataRepository extends CrudRepository<CostData, Long> {

    List<CostData> findByCostDataIdGreaterThanOrderByCostDataIdAsc(Long lastId);
}
```

Comment: Ditch all annotations only leave a plain `@SpringBootApplication`. That should make it work, assuming that your class is in the `com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator` package. Have you also read the error, the problem seems to be that the domain class you are referring to isn't an `@Entity` whilst you are using that in your Spring Data JPA repository.

Comment: @M.Deinum Just tried commenting all annotations out and going with at-SpringBootApplication plain, got same error. Application CostSSCFileGeneratorApplication is in com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator CostData is Entity in com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model

Comment: Please don't add additional code/errors as comments as those are unreadable. The error clearly states that `CostData` isn't an entity or at least a JPA managed type. So you must have forgotten some annotation on that class. All those annotations you added are solving the wrong thing and might even make things worse. Also your simplified and obfuscated code make it impossible to see if the packages are actually correct or not. Some state `com.ibm.` others `com.mycompany` or `com.mycomp`, making it impossible to determine which right.

Comment: @M.Deinum CostData has an at-javax.persistence.Entity annotation on it. What else could I be missing?

Comment: An `@Id` For instance. Basically all the classes you posted here, apart from the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class don't really matter for the issue. The once that do are the repository and the entity. With proper package names so that it is possible to determine if they structure of your application is right.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added the CostData entity. I think not sure what else it could be missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231336/discussion-between-woodsman-and-m-deinum).

Comment: As mentioned, your packages don't match up, so currently it is impossible to determine. Entity scanning isn't picking this up, or you are messing around with your own manually configured `EntityManagerFactory` or added a `persistence.xml` that disables scanning etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've shared the classes including the package statement. Which package and class does not line up? I've literally copied the full package into the entity annotation and it *still* doesn't find it.

Comment: The one on the @SpringBootApplication annotated class and the rest. Those packages are different. If they cannot be found they aren’t there, or as mentioned you have some confit for the entitmaangerfactory yourself. Basically there is something missing from the question which is relevant.

Comment: @M.Deinum All the packages on the annotations exist. They were all copy pasted. For the EntityScan annotation, the packages exist and the CostData entity was properly annotated, and duly added to the list of packages. As mentioned earlier, I shouldn't have had to do this. Also, all packages are child packages of the one that contains the application class. If you see something that does not line up, it would be helpful if you tell me. I already know it doesn't like something in this.

Comment: Try by replacing the existing anotations with these @EnableJpaRepositories("com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file"),@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.ibm.cio.cloud" }),@EntityScan("com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file")  and it's recommender to create repository classes in separate repository package and configure accoringly the base package name into enablejaprepositores anotation.

Comment: The package in which your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is is different then the other classes, at least according to what you posted here (which is what I told 2 times before as well). All those annotations make things worse, if they are in those packages they will be found, if they aren't they aren't. So as stated you are probably leaving something crucial piece of information out of this question like you have some custom config for `EntityManagerFactory` (asked 2 times before, no answer), other config disabling auto-configuruation, or perhaps a `persistence.xml` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effort was a copy of an existing project that did work, but I needed to refactor this for deployment to a cloud platform. I was hoping to get guidance that said something like you're missing the @SpringFinder annotation, or something similar or that somehow one of the annotations was missing. Instead, I scrapped the attempt and started over. The version that works has just the @SpringBootApplication, though I do not know what it did not like. Starting a fresh project helped.

Answer (score 0):

From the error logs, you are defining the repository CostDataRepository that manages the entity `com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostData` but the package `com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain` doen't figure in the `@EntityScan` you are configuring.

Also `@ComponentScan` is used for components not for entities, so you should drop this line.

Comment: I changed at-EntityScan to EntityScan({"com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model","com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application","com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.infrastructure.persistence","com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.infrastructure.persistence.file.system","com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.configuration"})
I have at-ComponentScan because there's a service I'm trying to get to run. I figured it's not going to cost much to overscan until I can get the right thing down.

Comment: It doesn't start because it doesn't find the CostData object.

Comment: if you use `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` correctely it should work. Did you make a refactoring before (changing the package name)? if so, try to clean the project. Or may be you have two classes with the same name and you put the wrong one in CostDataRepository.

Comment: I did an Eclipse Project->Clean and it still failed.

Comment: pleas post your last code for `CostDataRepository` and `BlueCostSSCFileGeneratorApplication` in order to check the configuration

Comment: Added CostDataRepository and the application is current as posted.

Comment: in `BlueCostSSCFileGeneratorApplication` the `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` still scan other packages than the one you are using replace them by `@EntityScan({"com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain"})` and 
`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.mycomp.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain"})`